# In App Purchase for existing Live App on App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

We've built an ionic app for android and iOS, android is working fine but for the iOS app we came across an issue of implementing In-App Purchases.

I did come across a few examples on how to implement In-App Purchases in the ionic iOS app.

**But my question is** if I create plans (records) in the In-App purchase in `itunesconnect`, will it affect my currently working app on App Store?

Can someone please guide me with this doubt.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding in-App purchase record in iTunesConnect won't affect your currently working app in terms of iTunesConnect.

In addition, you may need to add some check in your hybrid or backend code. In the situations that your backend waits for an in-app purchase action but your old version doesn't support it.

Below scheme from Apple Developer Document quotes how it is working

[image]

[In-App Purchase | Apple Developer Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in_app_purchase)